# Why Chrome is displaying this simple bootstrap header in two lines?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

The code below is displaying correctly in one line in both FF and IE but Chrome for some reason is displaying it in two lines as if both span and button elements had "display:block;". While I see that span has indeed computed display as block (because of the "float: left" as I could read elsewhere), but button has computed display as "inline-block" so it would seem that it should be rendered next to span and not below it.

It seems to behave like this with any version of Bootstrap >= 3.

Can anybody tell me why does Chrome behaves like?

(And I'm not asking how to place those element next to each other - I already found out that it works correctly when using ul and li elements)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap-3.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-3.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                <span class="navbar-text">User Name</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Log out</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what for the "navbar-btn" class inserted to button class?

Comment: Putting your external resources and code into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHUWx/), I see it all on one line.  Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107.

Comment: Yeah me too..nothing wrong

Comment: I'm running 32.0.1700.107 and I get the issue too. The Logout button appears on the second row. How it rearranged itself properly as soon as I opened my dev tools.

Comment: It seems that the bug is only evident when the width of the window is greater than 768px.

Comment: You can see the (not) working example here: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20258902/testcase/testcase.html)

Comment: I had the same exact issue and came up with a 'solution'. If you move your `button` just outside the `nav navbar` it looks great. Unfortunately for your case this may not be acceptable but hopefully it will lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar I see that the class="navbar navbar-nav" goes into a ul, so I tried it this way and it is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><span class="navbar-text">User Name</span></li>
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Log out</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I stated in my question I know that it's working with ul and li. I'm not asking how to place those elements with bootstrap but why they display like this in Chrome in a case I gave. So it's a question about how Chrome is interpreting css styles.